# Is there a way to open a file from solution explorer when drag and drop in code editor. VS 2010/2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, drag-and-drop, visual-studio-2012

I really would like to be able to open files while dragging and dropping it **from "Solution Explorer" to Code Editor(main) Window** in visual studio.

Is there a way to do that ? Can't believe Microsoft didn't think of that !

Visual Studio instead of opening the file creates a link to that file using its path. This is useless knowing that I can do the same just copy pasting the file into the Code editor.

It is possible though to open the files directly while dragging from Windows Explorer to Code Editor Window. I want the same with "Solution Explorer" !!!

Comment: By the code editor do you mean the main editor which is used to edit the files? Normally you double-lick the file to open it in the editor. I guess you have some reason why this does not suit you well? (Some special file type with a different default action on double-click?)

Comment: Yes that's what I mean ! I would like to be able to drag the file to the main editor ! WHY ? Because if I split the editor then I would be able to drag and drop to the window of my choice easily. I wouldn't need to preselect the window + double click

Comment: Why do you want that? Just double click and it will open :) It's better that drag n drop ads more functionality :)

Comment: I confess that I find it very strange that this feature does not exite in visual studio ... Go to program a plugin for it ? ^ ^

Comment: @Ankush right but if you have split your main editor in two or three ! it's really practical because by drag and dropping you can choose what split screen you want to display your file in.

Comment: I agree with @Arno2501 that drag-drop file from Solution Explorer should open the file in the editor. Its the most basic functionality that VS guys have missed it seems.